# Is it possible to use the format textbox(x).text to avoid several statements?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, textbox, controls

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim i as Integer
    i = ab.text 
    Dim x1 as double
    x1 = textbox(i).text
End Sub
```

'multiple statements

```
If cross1.Text = "1" Then
        Dim x1 As Double = xcoord((inches(aft1.Text, ain1.Text)), (inches(bft1.Text, bin1.Text)))
        xt1.Text = x1
        Dim y1 As Double = ycoord((inches(aft1.Text, ain1.Text)), (inches(bft1.Text, bin1.Text)))
        yt1.Text = y1
    ElseIf cross1.Text = "2" Then
        Dim x1 As Double = xcoord((inches(aft2.Text, ain2.Text)), (inches(bft2.Text, bin2.Text)))
        xt1.Text = x1
        Dim y1 As Double = ycoord((inches(aft2.Text, ain2.Text)), (inches(bft2.Text, bin2.Text)))
        yt1.Text = y1
    ElseIf cross1.Text = "3" Then
        Dim x1 As Double = xcoord((inches(aft3.Text, ain3.Text)), (inches(bft3.Text, bin3.Text)))
        xt1.Text = x1
        Dim y1 As Double = ycoord((inches(aft3.Text, ain3.Text)), (inches(bft3.Text, bin3.Text)))
        yt1.Text = y1
```

Comment: what is `textbox(i)` supposed to represent?  ALso turn on Option Strict

Comment: Show us the code that contains "several statements" and we can suggest a way to optimize it. Right now, your example is hard to analyse without context. Also, turn Option Strict On :)

Comment: I want the "1" to be aft(1).text ain(1).text etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation from the solution from Mr Wilko is through the creation of specific arrays of your controls.

```
Dim aftBoxes = new TextBox() {aft1, aft2, aft3}
Dim ainBoxes = new TextBox() {ain1, ain2, ain3}
Dim bftBoxes = new TextBox() {bft1, bft2, bft3}
Dim binBoxes = new TextBox() {bin1, bin2, bin3}

Dim index = Convert.ToInt32(cross1.Text) - 1
Dim x1 As Double = xcoord((inches(aftBoxes(index).Text, ainBoxes(index).Text)), 
                          (inches(bftBoxes(index).Text, binBoxes(index).Text)))
xt1.Text = x1
Dim y1 As Double = ycoord((inches(aftBoxes(index).Text, ainBoxes(index).Text)), 
                          (inches(bftBoxes(index).Text, binBoxes(index).Text)))
yt1.Text = y1
```

The advantage here is the fact that you can decide how to name your controls without having sequential names to retrieve them and also the order in which you read them (depending on the order in which you put them in the arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
'Find the textboxes based on the value in cross1.Text
Dim aftTxt As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("aft" + cross1.Text), TextBox) 
Dim bftTxt As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("bft" + cross1.Text), TextBox)    
Dim ainTxt As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("ain" + cross1.Text), TextBox) 
Dim binTxt As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("bin" + cross1.Text), TextBox) 

'now find the values based on the specfici textboxes
Dim x1 As Double = xcoord((inches(aftTxt.Text, ainTxt.Text)), (inches(bftTxt.Text, binTxt.Text)))
xt1.Text = x1
Dim y1 As Double = ycoord((inches(aftTxt.Text, ainTxt.Text)), (inches(bftTxt.Text, binTxt.Text)))
yt1.Text = y1
```